# android accessing variables through classes

Tags: android, class, variables

I have this application with 2 classes, in the first class I define a list array wich I want to access in my second class, how do I do that? class one (with the array extends listActivity and the other class extends `Activity`). I don't think it's nessecary to post my code as I believe there is a quick solution to this I just don't know it. Allthough I can post it if you can't help me without seeing the actual code.

Comment: http://androidideasblog.blogspot.in/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html

Comment: Seems to me like these examples all require me to make a class that implements parcelable? but I need to send my entire array from a listactivity class to an activity class, don't find anything here that works.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass `ArrayList<String>` 's across activities using intentExtras.

```
 ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
 // populate your array  -> if you want to send objects make a string form of them

 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Activit2.class);
 mtIntent.putStringArrayList("my_array_list", myArrayList);
```

In Activity2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 List<String> stringMediaList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("my_array_list");

for (int i = 0; i < stringMediaList.size(); i++) {
   //reconstruct object if needed
}
```

this will work if you dont want to use parcelable

Comment: Thanks alot man! worked great, just a last question though if you see this. How can I pass an int to another class? (no intArray just a regular int) there should be a similar way right?

Comment: Yes, myIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("my_integer_array", value) where value is a ArrayList<Integer>.  

For regular int's  use myIntent.putExtra("my_int" , 9001);

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `ApplicationContext` to share global state between activities - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/780271) for more details...